# How does deleting a contact work with a custom sync adapter in Android?

Tags: android, contacts, adapter, synchronization

I wrote an app that uses a custom sync adapter for contacts, and it works perfectly for synching / adding / editing contacts. However, I can't figure out how t get my app (or the sync adapter service) to be notified when a contact was deleted on the local device. Here is the scenario now:

1. A user deletes the contact using the native Contacts app
2. That contact gets marked for deletion and removed from my custom sync adapter (it no longer shows up in the Contacts app)
3. During the next sync, my sync adapter can see that the contact was marked for deletion, but there is no timestamp to know when this was done

I would like to have my app notified when the user deletes the contact in Step 1, and then immediately process that deletion. How can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your syncadapter configured to sync automatically & is master-sync-automatically enabled? In that case the behavior you are describing is very odd - a sync *should* be triggered shortly after a delete in the native Contacts app. The methods for setting/reading auto sync are available through the ContentResolver class.

Comment: It's definitely set up to sync. i'm using the follwoing 2 lines when creating the sync account:            ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(acct, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, 1);
               ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(acct, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, true);

Comment: Whats the master sync setting, ContentResolver#getMasterSyncAutomatically()? If that is also true something very odd is happening to your adapter.

Comment: Master Sync is ON. I think I'm getting close to figuring this out -- the sync does get triggered, but it takes over a minute for that to happen after the contact is deleted. I assume that there is a setting somewhere in Android OS that delays the sync in case there are multiple changes to contacts, and it wants to do them all at once. Otherwise, I have no idea why it takes that long

Comment: Well yes, it's not immediate - it's waiting in case "changes stack up", but at least it appears your solution is working. Gl.

Comment: Is there any way to control the timeout period before the sync gets triggered?

Comment: Nope, those are all constants defined in the SyncManager implementation afaik.

Comment: i cannot understand one thing: when i delete a contact in the native app, and some time after my sync adapter runs, isn't there a possibility that the google sync adapter got executed before mine and synced and deleted the row from the provider???